# Multiple updates on same field in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

So I've been struggling with the atomic operations in MongoDB, I have an array of strings in a field and I want to replace some of its values with another set of values. Namely, capabilities of a certain user.

```
db.test.insert({capabilities:["capability1","capability2","capability3"]})
```

Basically let's say the user changed their subscription to have "capability4" instead of "capability2" and "capability3". Is there a way (even a work around) to do this in mongodb? (Leaving capability1 untouched of course). I looked into the two phase commit explanation in the mongodb docs and it looks too convoluted for what I want to do, also it's made across multiple collections which is not the case for me.

Comment: take a look at [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

Comment: Sorry, but can you provide more details about your issue? Are you experiencing problem with parallel updates? Or you have issues updating element inside an array?

Comment: Whatever way you shake it this comes down to either a.) Overwriting the entire array with `$set` b ) Working out the difference in the client and issuing multiple `$push` and `$pull` operations, preferably in bulk operations. If you are prepared to ditch the array then you could always look at [`$bit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/bit/#up._S_bit)

Comment: @Artyom I am not experiencing problems with multiple updates, no, I just want to replace a subset of an array for another in one atomic operation for data consistency, if I read -> write I can get some problems with reading wrong data ..etc

Comment: @NeilLunn I like the [$bit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/bit/#up._S_bit) idea but the problem this field needs to stay an array for compatibility purposes. The $set means I need to read then write..which causes the data consistency problem :/

Comment: Sorry, but what you mean by read before write? How you can get wrong data if you didn't initiate update yet? Is your data really look that way (as in example), do you have user id or something similar? I mean if your "test" collection has "users" with field "capabilities", then $set should work fine, but if you have a collection with just entity "capabilities" how you map it to a user?

Comment: Well by that logic you are left with `$push` and `$pull` operations in bulk. So your question seems answered when you discount the other possible things you can do then you are left with the only one thing you can do.

Comment: @Artyom I mean if some other process reads the data while I am in between updating and reading the data. Like if the user refreshes the page and gets the old capabilities instead of the new ones. The data provided is just a stripped down version of the entire object as the rest is irrelevant to the question, but yea, it contains a user id, email and a couple more things. The $set wouldn't work because it would completely reset the field with the new capabilities and not replace some items with some other items.

Comment: @NeilLunn I think maybe I will try out the bulk operations indeed if there are no other solutions.

Comment: Well that's the list https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/ and if it isn't there then MongoDB does not do it. I gather you have already worked out that `$push` and `$pull` cannot be done in the same update request since it's a rule that no two operations can modify the same document path in a request. BTW two phase commit is overkill here if making atomic array changes.

Comment: Is "capabilities" a property of "user" entity? $set is atomic operation, if you populate/modify "capabilities" array on UI/Backend side, and use $set on whole array, it should be fine.

Comment: @Artyom If you read through the comments here the OP has already ruled out overwriting the array with `$set`. Yes it's atomic, but under a heavy write/read load there is no guarantee that something is not going to get the wrong picture. I.e If a `$push` is made to the array between the "read" and the `$set`, then you overwrite the added item from the `$push` that the reader operation did not see. So that's the reason.

Comment: @NeilLunn Sorry, if i get it wrong, but in my first comment, i was asking what is the source of the issue, is it a parallel updates or not. I am not forcing Bola to use $set, i just have a feeling that we got it wrongly. Question description and code example is not perfect.

Comment: Mongodb does not offer transactional lock on collections or documents. So your best choice is to make your update in one operation. And as @Artyom said your only option is to use $set operator. After reading user document, build capabilities array with new added capabilities and exist capabilities and then set the array in one operation.

Comment: @Artyom it's only backend modification on the array. If it was UI, the solution would've been `$set` indeed, but the problem is if I want to move a user from a plan to another plan with a different set of capabilities, but at the same time, the user can have other capabilities than plan capabilities. That means that I need to read the user capabilities on the client side and then remove/replace old capabilities with new ones. This explanation is not atomic, it's two consecutive operations on the database, leaving time in between so if something else updates the array in between, it's a mess.

Comment: In this case, probably, you would need to implement some sort of transaction/locking yourself.

Comment: @Bola you can always keep plan capabilities in other field than custom ones and then make the distinction transparent in your code